# Detect Mobile view in zend framework not happening?

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
UPDATED MY QUESTION
```

I am trying to implement the seperate template for mobile view using zend framework. I am following this [guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html#zend.http.user-agent.quick-start)

I have the following plugin called `Mobile.php`

```
<?php

class ZC_Controller_Plugin_Mobile extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) { 

    $bootstrap  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam("bootstrap"); 
    $useragent  = $bootstrap->getResource("useragent"); 
    $device     = $useragent->getDevice(); 

    Zend_Registry::set("useragent", $useragent);
    Zend_Registry::set("device", $device);

    /**
     * @todo change this to be Mobile 
     */

    echo $device->getType() . " is the type of device";

}

}
```

This works in Desktop view.I got `desktop is the type of device` as the output when i run the site.When check the same , i got the following Application error,

[image]

I am getting the error in this following line when i run site on mobile              `$device     = $useragent->getDevice();`

Kindly advice on this

Comment: Please post the whole error message.

Comment: @Iznogood Thanks,I could not copy the error in ipad simulator.i upload screenshot. Kindly check

Comment: Do you have the latest WURFL version?

Comment: You don't actually have to set the correct version in your `application.ini` file.  You can set it to **1.1** even if it's not the version you're using.  Otherwise, I manually added `case: '1.4'` to `Zend_Http_UserAgent_Features_Adapter_WurflApi` so it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Zend Framework currently only works with WURFL version `1.0` and `1.1` (see `Zend_Http_UserAgent_Features_Adapter_WurflApi`).

Unfortunately, only the latest 2 versions are available and the older versions were pulled for some reason and are not available for download from SourceForge.  You have a newer version `1.3.0`.  `1.3.1` is the latest version as of writing.

I couldn't find the `1.1` version anywhere except for one site [here](http://leolanese.com/wurfl/WURFL%20PHP/1.1/).  I don't know the source, or the integrity of the version posted there, but I looked through a lot of the files and it looks like what you need.

I would recommend downloading that version and replacing the other files with these and see if the error goes away.

Hope that helps.